# Windowscryptographicexception - the specified network password is not correct

Tags: x509certificate

I've created a .Net Core 3.1 application and have the following code in my program class:

```
var x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(“test.pfx”, “password”, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

When the code runs, the following exception occurs:
Windowscryptographicexception - 'the specified network password is not correct'

I know the password is correct, so in this case, is there anything else which could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of this work, I had retrieved the password from an old config file, which has to espape an & value with an ampersand. Hence, when I tried, it was actually wrong.

Created my own certificate through pluralsight tool and tested with this and no issues.

Apologies!